# HDFS FileSplit locations

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, filesplitting

I have a cluster with an installation of hadoop-2.1.0-beta. Is there a way to learn where each filesplit is located in my cluster? What I am looking for is a list such as the following

```
filesplit_0001 node1
filesplit_0002 node4
...
```

edit: I know that such a list is available in Microsoft Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***fsck*** tool provides an easy way to find out which blocks are in any particular file. For example:

```
% hadoop fsck <path> -files -blocks -locations -racks
```

Reference : [Hadoop Command Line Guide.](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/commands_manual.html#fsck)

**Edit:**

An input split is a chunk of the input that is processed by a single map. Each map processes a single split. Each split is divided into records, and the map processes each record a key-value pair in turn. **Splits and records are logical but HDFS blocks are physical.**

An `InputSplit` has a length in bytes and a set of storage locations, which are just hostname strings. A split doesn’t contain the input data; it is just a reference to the data.

You can get `InputSplit` instance in `map` method.

```
InputSplit inputSplit=context.getInputSplit(); //Input split instance 
String[] splitLocations = inputSplit.getLocations();
```

Comment: thanks @mgs, this is a good answer in case block size equals filesplit size. But in my case the two have different sizes.